# Why was Railgun chosen for the Sisters project and not Kakine Teitoku?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index, a-certain-scientific-railgun, a-certain-scientific-accelerator

Misaka Mikoto "Railgun" was chosen for the Sisters project who cloned her. But she's ranked #3 among the level 5 espers. Why wasnt rank #2 Kakine Teitoku chosen instead, or even rank #1 Accelerator, in the case the original objective of the project wasnt to turn Accelerator into a level 6?

Answer (score 2):

if I remember correctly the electric powers allowed the clones to form "the misaka network", so they can learn from the previous battles and get stronger over time.

> [ref: clip from To aru Kagaku no Railgun S](https://youtu.be/p3jhTaFfG98?t=89)